# Show that angular momentum can be divided into center of mass and internal coordinate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, cross-product

This might belong in physics but I want to be sure I am approaching the math right.

Given: show angular momentum can be divided into separate parts of the center of mass and internal coordinates.

So I start with vector $\mathbf R$ as the coordinate for the center of mass and $\mathbf r_i$ for the $i^{th}$ particle, and say that $\mathbf r_i'$ is the coordinate of the $i^{th}$ particle in terms of the internal coordinates, and further $\mathbf r_i = \mathbf R + \mathbf r_i'$

Angular momentum $\mathbf L$ is $$\mathbf L = \sum_i \mathbf r_i \times \mathbf p = \sum_i \mathbf r_i \times (m_i \mathbf{\dot r_i})$$ because p=mv and v is the derivative of the position vector.

OK, so I know that $\mathbf r_i = \mathbf R + \mathbf r_i'$ which means I can plug that into the summation. I get $$\mathbf L = \sum_i (\mathbf R + \mathbf r_i') \times (m_i \mathbf{\dot r_i})$$
further I know that if I take a derivative w/r/t time of my original expression $\mathbf r_i = \mathbf R + \mathbf r_i'$ I should get $\mathbf {\dot r_i} = \mathbf {\dot R} + \mathbf {\dot r_i'}$ and I can plug that in to get $$\mathbf L = \sum_i (\mathbf R + \mathbf r_i') \times (m_i \mathbf {\dot R} + m_i \mathbf {\dot r_i'})$$

and it's the last step where I kept getting answers that didn't make sense to me, unless there's some stupid-simple identity I am missing. I feel that two terms should go to zero and that should be that. But I wasn't sure how that kind of vector multiple distributes. I have my parts there -- I can see them (assuming I did everything else right). But I feel like the very last step is stopping me.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you expect in final form

Comment: I expected 2 terms -- one for the angular momentum of the center of mass and one for that of the internal coordinates -- essentially $L_{cm} + L_{internal} = \mathbf L$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of centre of mass, you have $\sum_i R m_i = \sum_i m_i r_i = \sum_i m_i (R + r_i')$, and so $\sum_i m_i r_i' = 0$. It follows that $\sum_i m_i \dot{r}_i' = 0$ also.

Expanding
\begin{eqnarray}
L &=& \sum_i (R + r_i') \times (m_i \dot{R}+ m_i \dot{r}_i')\\
&=&
\sum_i R \times m_i \dot{R}
+ \sum_i r_i' \times m_i \dot{R} 
+ \sum_i R \times m_i \dot{r}_i'  +
\sum_i r_i' \times m_i \dot{r}_i' \\
&=&
 R \times (\sum_i m_i) \dot{R}
+ (\sum_i m_i r_i') \times \dot{R} 
+ R \times (\sum_i  m_i \dot{r}_i')  +
\sum_i r_i' \times m_i \dot{r}_i' \\
&=&
 R \times (\sum_i m_i) \dot{R} +
0 \times \dot{R}  + R \times 0 +
\sum_i r_i' \times m_i \dot{r}_i' \\
&=&
 R \times (\sum_i m_i) \dot{R} +
\sum_i r_i' \times m_i \dot{r}_i' \\
&=& L_{\text{com}} + L_{\text{internal}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: thanks to you both. silly of me, since yes, by definition the COM is at the center of whatever coordinate system you are using.

Comment: By the way shouldn't the third term in the second line be $\sum_i R \times m_i \dot{r_i'}$

Comment: @Jesse: Good catch! I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  To eliminate the cross terms, use the definition of centre of mass, viz.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_i m_i \mathbf {r_i'} = 0 && \sum_i m_i \mathbf {\dot r_i'} = 0
\end{align}$$